# What is causing my "vector memory exhausted" error?

Tags: r, memory

For context: I am running a large simulation that takes many hours and 30+ iterations. Everytime, seemingly randomly between 16 and 23 iterations, I get the following error:

[image]

I believe I've narrowed down the issue to the following code block (which is not surprising given that this is one of the slowest steps of the algorithm):

```r
adj_mat <- dists_mat
  
  a <- (adj_mat <= cutoff)
  b <- (adj_mat > cutoff)
  
  adj_mat[a] <- TRUE
  adj_mat[b] <- FALSE
```

`adj_mat` is a very large 2,000 x 40,000 distance matrix. In the code block, I am trying to binarize all the cells of this matrix using a cutoff value. Step 1 is to assign the coordinates of all the 1 and 0 cells to the variables `a` and `b`, respectively. Step 2 is then to assign 1s and 0s to those coordinates in the matrix.

I just don't understand why this code works for 10+ iterations and then exhausts the vector memory. I'm not saving very much data within the function after each iteration.

Is there perhaps a more **memory efficient/less computationally demanding** way to binarize that matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this will help but you can reduce this to only two lines. This will avoid creation of all temporary variables and remove  additional steps.

```
adj_mat <- dists_mat
adj_mat <- adj_mat <= cutoff
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `split` and create a `list` of output in a single line

```
lst1 <- split(adj_mat, adj_mat <= cutoff)
```